# How to iteratively add rows of one tibble to tibbles within a list of tibbles?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Given a list of tibbles

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

ltb <- list(tibble(a=1:10, b=1:10), tibble(a=1:10, b=1:10), tibble(a=1:10, b=1:10))

map(ltb, ~head(., 2))
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      a     b
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     2

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      a     b
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     2

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      a     b
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     2
```

and another single tibble whose number of rows matches the number of elements in the above list

```
tib <- tibble(data1 = letters[1:3], data2 = LETTERS[1:3], data3 = letters[1:3])

> tib
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  data1 data2 data3
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     A     a    
2 b     B     b    
3 c     C     c
```

how can I bind the first row of `tib` to the first tibble in `ltb`, the second row of `tib` to the second tibble in `ltb`? Obviously, this should recycle the rows in `tib` to (dynamically) match the number of rows in each tibble in `ltb`.

So the result should look something like this

```
map(newltb, ~head(., 3))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      a     b data1 data2 data3
  <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1     1   a     A     a    
2     2     2   a     A     a    
3     3     3   a     A     a    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      a     b data1 data2 data3
  <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1     1   b     B     b    
2     2     2   b     B     b    
3     3     3   b     B     b    

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      a     b data1 data2 data3
  <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1     1   c     C     c    
2     2     2   c     C     c    
3     3     3   c     C     c
```

I struggle whether to use `map2` or `pmap2`, neither one have worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could split `tib` by rows and use `map2` and `bind_cols` like so:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(purrr)

ltb <- list(tibble(a=1:10, b=1:10), tibble(a=1:10, b=1:10), tibble(a=1:10, b=1:10))

tib <- tibble(data1 = letters[1:3], data2 = LETTERS[1:3], data3 = letters[1:3])

tib_split <- tib %>%
  split(seq(nrow(.)))

map2(ltb, tib_split, bind_cols)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>        a     b data1 data2 data3
#>    <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1     1     1 a     A     a    
#>  2     2     2 a     A     a    
#>  3     3     3 a     A     a    
#>  4     4     4 a     A     a    
#>  5     5     5 a     A     a    
#>  6     6     6 a     A     a    
#>  7     7     7 a     A     a    
#>  8     8     8 a     A     a    
#>  9     9     9 a     A     a    
#> 10    10    10 a     A     a    
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>        a     b data1 data2 data3
#>    <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1     1     1 b     B     b    
#>  2     2     2 b     B     b    
#>  3     3     3 b     B     b    
#>  4     4     4 b     B     b    
#>  5     5     5 b     B     b    
#>  6     6     6 b     B     b    
#>  7     7     7 b     B     b    
#>  8     8     8 b     B     b    
#>  9     9     9 b     B     b    
#> 10    10    10 b     B     b    
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>        a     b data1 data2 data3
#>    <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1     1     1 c     C     c    
#>  2     2     2 c     C     c    
#>  3     3     3 c     C     c    
#>  4     4     4 c     C     c    
#>  5     5     5 c     C     c    
#>  6     6     6 c     C     c    
#>  7     7     7 c     C     c    
#>  8     8     8 c     C     c    
#>  9     9     9 c     C     c    
#> 10    10    10 c     C     c
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, can use a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(ltb)) ltb[[i]][names(tib)] <- tib[i,]
```

-output

```
> ltb
[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 × 5
       a     b data1 data2 data3
   <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1     1     1 a     A     a    
 2     2     2 a     A     a    
 3     3     3 a     A     a    
 4     4     4 a     A     a    
 5     5     5 a     A     a    
 6     6     6 a     A     a    
 7     7     7 a     A     a    
 8     8     8 a     A     a    
 9     9     9 a     A     a    
10    10    10 a     A     a    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 × 5
       a     b data1 data2 data3
   <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1     1     1 b     B     b    
 2     2     2 b     B     b    
 3     3     3 b     B     b    
 4     4     4 b     B     b    
 5     5     5 b     B     b    
 6     6     6 b     B     b    
 7     7     7 b     B     b    
 8     8     8 b     B     b    
 9     9     9 b     B     b    
10    10    10 b     B     b    

[[3]]
# A tibble: 10 × 5
       a     b data1 data2 data3
   <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1     1     1 c     C     c    
 2     2     2 c     C     c    
 3     3     3 c     C     c    
 4     4     4 c     C     c    
 5     5     5 c     C     c    
 6     6     6 c     C     c    
 7     7     7 c     C     c    
 8     8     8 c     C     c    
 9     9     9 c     C     c    
10    10    10 c     C     c
```